# Send email when submitting google form

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

I'm not a programmer but I need this script to send automatic e-mails for the last row only when somebody submits a GoogleForm. I don't have any idea how to do it. There is my script:

```js
function sendMail()
{
  
    var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email");
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Respostas ao formulário 1");
    var data = ws.getLastRow("A:G").getValues();

      data.forEach(function(row){
      
      emailTemp.NOME = row[nome];
      emailTemp.ID = row[id];
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();

      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        row[email],
        "Inscrição no curso de Aromaterapia Vanusa Feitosa", 
        "Seu E-mail não suporta HTML.",
        {name: "Instituto Vanusa Feitosa", htmlBody: htmlMessage}  
    );

});
```

Comment: I need that when somebody sobmitting a googleForm, the script send auomatic e-mail, but only the last row, and not all rows, to not send repeted e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Installable Trigger.

> Installable triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event occurs. Example: form submitted.

This will make sure that the email we will send is from the latest submitted form.

**How to create Installable Trigger?**

> - Open your Apps Script project.
> - At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> - At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> - Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create. For this case, Click the drop down menu below **Select event type** and select **On form submit**
> - Click Save.

Your trigger should look like this:

[image]

### Example:

**Form:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function sendEmail(e) {
  var response = e.namedValues;
  var name = response['Name'];
  var email = response['Email'];
  var subject = "Inscrição no curso de Aromaterapia Vanusa Feitosa";
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email');
  templ.name = name;
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent(); 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, '', {
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

**Email.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
    Hello <?= name ?>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Response:**

[image: response]

**Email:**

[image]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)